# How do select the subsequent rows with the same attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am transforming from xml to xml between two different formats.

My question:
How do i select the a sequence of subfields with the code 'B' that is a following sibling to 'A' but not the not to any other field. 
If anyone can help me figure out how to "select" the correct nodes

Restrictions:
 - XSLT 1.0
 - I can't change the order of the content in datafields and due to the
   amount of different posts. Different rulesets are applied based on previous and following subfields.
 - I can't use specific positions(there no guarantee that 2 subfields
   'B' will follow 'A' or similar)

Example:
Each post contains datafields with any number of subfields.

XML is similar to this

```
<datafield tag="1">
      <subfield code="A"></subfield>
      <subfield code="B"></subfield>
      <subfield code="B"></subfield>
      <subfield code="C"></subfield>
      <subfield code="D"></subfield>
      <subfield code="B"></subfield>
      <subfield code="B"></subfield>
      <subfield code="G"></subfield>      
</datafield>
```

My xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="datafield[@tag=1]">    
<xsl:choose>    
    <datafield>        
      <xsl:attribute name="tag">new tag</xsl:attribute>                    
      <!-- Do not transfer subfield code='X' -->
      <xsl:for-each select="./subfield[@code != 'X']">           
        <subfield>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="./@code = 'A'">
              <xsl:attribute name="code">New code</xsl:attribute>     
                <!-- Find siblings with the code 'B'.PROBLEM all fields with the code B is selected-->
              <xsl:when test="./following-sibling::subfield[@code='B']"> Apply operation here </xsl:when>
              </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>                
        </subfield>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </datafield>
  </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

I'm a pretty new stackoverflow user so if i missed any vital input please tell me and ill add it.

Comment: I believe you want to use a **key** here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to do something based on counts - select all the following Bs whose number of preceding non-Bs is the same as the number of *my* preceding non-Bs plus one (i.e. me)

```
following-sibling::subfield[@code='B']
       [count(preceding-sibling::subfield[not(@code='B')])
      = count(current()/preceding-sibling::subfield[not(@code='B')]) + 1]
```

A more efficient way might be to define a *key* grouping Bs by their nearest preceding non-B

```
<xsl:key name="BbyNonB" match="subfield[@code='B']"
         use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::subfield[not(@code='B')][1])" />
```

and then you can extract all the Bs immediately following the current (non-B) subfield with

```
key('BbyNonB', generate-id())
```

Comment: Can't get the key part to work due to lacking knowledge in how they are used but the top select worked like a charm. Will return and give a upvote when i have enough reputation for it.

Comment: @Marcus the `xsl:key` definition has to go outside the templates as a direct child of `xsl:stylesheet`, if you search on SO you'll see many examples of the necessary syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Ian's answer was really great. I am not contesting that at all. But personally, I found it easier to learn XSLT thinking in terms of recursive functions. If that's also the case for you, consider this solution. Again, as a beginner, thinking in terms of functions calls was easier for me. But Ian's answer is obviously much shorter and cooler.

Here's the XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>                    
 <xsl:template match="subfield[@code='A']">
  <xsl:for-each select=".">
    <xsl:call-template name="getB">
      <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="./following-sibling::subfield"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="getB">
<xsl:param name="nodes"/>
  <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="$nodes[1][@code='B']">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$nodes[1]"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="getB">
           <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$nodes[position() > 1]"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise/>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For this input:

```
 <datafield tag="1">
  <subfield code="A"></subfield>
  <subfield code="B"></subfield>
  <subfield code="B"></subfield>
  <subfield code="C"></subfield>
  <subfield code="D"></subfield>
  <subfield code="B"></subfield>
  <subfield code="B"></subfield>
  <subfield code="G"></subfield>      
 </datafield>
```

You get this output:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <subfield code="B"/>
  <subfield code="B"/>
```

But if this kind of solutions doesn't help, simply ignore it.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I went with Ian's solution but I'm sure this can help someone else.

Comment: "*I found it easier to learn XSLT thinking in terms of recursive functions.*" I am not sure that's what "XSLT thinking" is really about.

Comment: Michael, maybe I should have been more clear. I wasn't speaking about "XSLT thinking", I was saying: "I found it easier to learn XSLT, [by] thinking in terms of recursive functions." That's all. You are obviously very experienced at this. Which means you have lots of great, clever, and advanced solutions. For someone still learning the ropes (as I still consider myself to be), I personally found it helpful to approach XSLT problems from the perspective of functional programming and recursion, because that was my background. I was just speaking to Marcus as a fellow beginner.